# OpenURI fails to follow URLs that have %20

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am having some issues with Ruby's OpenURI follow redirect functionality.

When going to a URL that contains `%20` in it, and that redirects with a 30x, Ruby's OpenURI fails.

- The exact same URL, with a `+` instead of `%20` works.
- Both the `%20` and `+` versions work properly with `curl -L` (follow).

#### Code

```
require 'open-uri'

base = "http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook"

puts "===> PASS: URI Open +"
result = open "#{base}/Video+Series"
p result.status

puts "===> PASS: Curl +"
puts `curl -LIsS "#{base}/Video+Series" | grep HTTP`

puts "===> PASS: Curl %20"
puts `curl -LIsS "#{base}/Video%20Series" | grep HTTP`

puts "===> FAIL: URI Open %20"
begin
  result = open "#{base}/Video%20Series"
  p result.status
rescue => e
  puts "#{e.class} #{e.message}"
end
```

#### Output

```
===> PASS: URI Open +
["200", "OK"]
===> PASS: Curl +
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
===> PASS: Curl %20
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
===> FAIL: URI Open %20
OpenURI::HTTPError 302 Found (Invalid Location URI)
```

I am not sure what is going on here. Tried HTTParty (although I know it is just a wrapper), hoping to see a different behavior, but it also fails.

Comment: Not at all. The mentioned question is not related, besides the fact that it mentions spaces in URL encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is responding with an redirect to an invalid URI. `curl` is being lax about it, but Ruby is being strict.

If we print out the `e.cause` we get more information.

```
#<URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook/Video Series/">
```

And also by looking at the headers from `curl -I 'http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook/Video%20Series'`...

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Server: Cowboy
Date: Sat, 28 Dec 2019 21:41:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Location: http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook/Video Series/
```

And, indeed, the server is returning an invalid URI. Spaces are not allowed in a [URI path](https://pretty-rfc.herokuapp.com/RFC3986#path). Ruby's URI class will not parse it.

```
> URI("http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook/Video Series/")
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://software-engineering-handbook.com/Handbook/Video Series/"
from /Users/schwern/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only HTTP client I found that does not understand this. Even Ruby's HTTP gem follows it properly. I will probably switch to it instead.

Comment: Don't use the HTTP library unless you're designing a new client from scratch. Instead use one of the many HTTP clients that already exist. Writing a client that covers all the bases wastes your time when other excellent ones already exist.